# Java Class Method Error android

Tags: android, eclipse, oop, methods, runtime-error

I have a method inside of a standard Java class that takes in a `String[]` as a parameter and returns a `String[]`. Basically the method is reading the Shared Preferences and returning a `String[]`. Here it is:

```
public static String[] getPrefs(){
    String tempString = settings.getString("123", "0");
    if(tempString == ("0")){
        //show some type of error
        return null;
    }
    String[] ToReturn = tempString.split("@,#");
    return ToReturn;
```

And the Error:

Here is a link to a picture with [my error](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwnXiiCsRNnnclZBTW1ULTc4cjg/edit?usp=drive_web&authuser=0) at line 3.
I also got an error that didn't say much other than that it was at line 4.

Before you ask, the LogCat didn't give any more info than what I just list. These are all runtime errors and eclipse doesn't detect any errors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For future reference, you should copy and paste the error message here. In particular, this insures that those details are available for anyone with a similar issue in the future. You might decide to delete the graphic file from your Google Docs account which will make this question less helpful to future visitors.

Comment: `tempString == (0)` compares a `String` to an `int`. This will result in a compiler error. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line to

```
if (tempString == null) {
    //show some type of error
    return null;
}
```

This is how you check for `null`, not by calling `.equals()`. Calling `.equals()` (or any method) on a `null` object will cause a `NullPointerException`.

**Edit**: After your third edit, you need to change it to

```
if(tempString.equals("0")){
```

Since `tempString` will no longer default to `null`, as it did prior to your edit.

Comment: I don't care if I use the condition variable. I just put that in there  because of compatibility with the return statement. I just want the if statement to check if the string is null, and if it is, return null. I updated my question.

Comment: Fine. It's erroring because you are calling `.equals()` on a `null` object. Check for null with `== null`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I have edited my code in my question and it goes into the if-then properly, but how do I use that return statement within the if-then because when I tried it, it didn't return that and kept on going with the method?

Comment: You've changed it again. Now you need to my answer to `if(tempString.equals("0")){`. **Checking for null is a special case and different from checking for anything else **. You are no longer checking for null. You are checking if it equals the string "0". So you have to use `.equals()`

Comment: Is there a way to return that `null` value from within the `if` statement? It just continues on with the method right now.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking anymore. I think I answered your original question of "why am I getting this error". Hopefully I've helped. Maybe someone else can answer or alternatively please create a new, more specific question.

Comment: Sorry about getting away from the question, I will start this question on a new thread.